# Native extension removed from AIR, but still getting error related to it "Duplicate platform Android-ARM found for extension"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, ane

I tried the mateuszmackowiak.nativeANE.NativeDialogs ANE, but now I'm still getting this error in Flash CC, although ANE is removed:

> The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an
>   extension: Error: Duplicate platform Android-ARM found for extension
>   pl.mateuszmackowiak.nativeANE.NativeDialogs

Error appears every time I add an ANE in Flash CC, any ANE.

What I've done:

- Removed the extension from Flash
- Checked app.xml and removed reference to it
- Removed everything related to that ANE from main class
- "Clear publish cache and test movie"
- Removed the folder from project's directory
- Searched every file in project's directory for "mateuszmackowiak" and no result

Any idea/help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by removing the extension from temp directory in windows. Just search the temp directory for that ANE and delete the folder.

In my case the link was: 
C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\Tmp_ANE_File_Unzipped_Packages